# How to share the same email session between all instances of the application?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

Maybe this question is already answered, but I couldn't find the proper answer.
I have a web application based in JSF, and I want to share the same email session between all the instances of the application, yet I haven't found how to do that.

My questions are:

a) What I am thinking is stupid? Should I just create a new session every time that I want to send a new mail?

b) If a is false, is there a proper way to do that?

Additional info: I'm working with PrimeFaces 4.0, Apache Tomcat 7.0.41, and JDK 7.

**EDIT:** I'm establishing an email connection like this (using sun's java mail)

```
    Properties datos = new Properties();
    datos.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    datos.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    datos.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    datos.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", usuarioAutenticacion);
    datos.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 5000);
    System.out.println(usuarioAutenticacion + " - " + contrasenaAutenticacion);
    sesionCorreo = Session.getDefaultInstance(datos, null);
    sesionCorreo.setDebug(true);

    try {
        conexionCorreo = sesionCorreo.getTransport("smtp");
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NotificacionesManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        conexionCorreo.connect(usuarioAutenticacion, contrasenaAutenticacion);
```

Then I proceed to send the messages in the Queue, but I'm looking for a way for just set that connection once then start sending the mails in the queue when necessary.

Comment: What do you mean with _email session_? Do you have some code to explain it?

Comment: Done, sorry I though the question was too simple that it didn't need code.

Comment: What do you mean multiple instances? Do you mean multiple instances of your application deployed to different containers with a load balancer in front, or something? That is, what are you "sharing the session" between, exactly, and what do you hope to achieve by doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the Java EE designers intended you to do this is that you configure your javax.mail.Session object in your server. This is described in the [Tomcat 7 JavaMail Sessions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JavaMail_Sessions) documentation.

Your managed beans should then be able to access the session via @Resource:

```
class MyManagedBean {

    @Resource(name="mail/Session") // this name is defined by your configuration
    private Session mailSession;


    public void someBusinessMethod() {
         ...
         Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
         // compose message
         ...
         Transport.send(message);
    }

}
```

If you need to do this from a non-managed bean then you grab your Session instance using JNDI. This is described in the documentation linked above.